# Splitting text based on its offset value and push it to new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

I wanted to break down `paragraph`  based on it’s `entityRanges`.

So the actual paragraph looks like this,

```
{
    type: 'paragraph',
    depth: 1,
    text: 'Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.',
    entityRanges: [{
        type: 'LINK',
        offset: 83,
        length: 16,
        data: {
            target: '_self',
            url: '/index.htm'
        }
    }]
}
```

But my expected results should be like below,

```
{
    type: 'paragraph',
    depth: 1,
    text: 'Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.',
    entityRanges: [{
        type: 'LINK',
        offset: 83,
        length: 16,
        data: {
            target: '_self',
            url: '/index.htm'
        }
    }],
    embbeded: [{
        type: 'text',
        text: 'Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our '
    }, {
        type: 'link',
        text: 'customer support',
        data: {
            target: '_self',
            url: '/index.htm'
        }
    }, {
        type: 'text',
        text: 'page.'
    }]
}
```

I wanted to break down the `text` into multiple parts based on it’s `offset` & `length` values.

As per the example, `customer support` is the offset value.

So it should breakdown in the below order

1. Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC?
   Please visit our
2. customer support
3. page.

All above parts needs to pushed to new object `embbeded`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understood you correctly:

```js
const data = {
  "text": "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.",
  "entityRanges": [{
      "type": "LINK",
      "offset": 83,
      "length": 16,
      "data": {
        "target": "_self",
        "url": "/index.htm"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "LINK",
      "offset": 7,
      "length": 4,
      "data": {
        "target": "_self",
        "url": "/index.htm"
      }
    }
  ]
};

function breakData(data) {
  let {
    entityRanges,
    text
  } = data;
  const result = [];
  let finalPart = '';
  let index = 0;

  entityRanges
    .sort((a, b) => a.offset - b.offset)
    .forEach((styleRange) => {
      const {
        offset,
        length,
        type,
        data
      } = styleRange;
      const firstPart = text.substring(index, offset);

      result.push({
        type: 'text',
        text: firstPart,
      });

      index = offset + length; // + 1;
      const secondPart = text.substring(offset, index);
      result.push({
        type,
        data,
        text: secondPart,
      });

      finalPart = text.substring(index);
    });

  if (finalPart) {
    result.push({
      type: 'text',
      text: finalPart,
    });
  }
  data.embbeded = result;

  return data;
}

const result = breakData(data);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, ' ') + '</pre>';
```